# Bitmap larger than original image

Tags: c#, image, memory, bitmap, size

I'm loading a bitmap in memory and it seems to me is consuming more memory than the original image size in disk.

The original image is 16bpp so an image of 512x512 will be about 512K. When I load this into memory using the Bitmap Class, it transforms the image to 32bpp therefore it goes:
512X512X4=1MB instead of the regular 512K I would expect.

Is there a way to store just the image with the original size?

Thanks,

EDIT:
Here's the code I'm using:

```
 System.Drawing.Image MyImage = new Bitmap(img.RenderImage(0)); //img is a DicomFile and the RenderImage Method returns a System.Drawing.Image
```

MyImage size in memory is almost double than the original image size in disk.

The RenderImage method is here:
https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom/blob/master/DICOM/Imaging/Render/ImageGraphic.cs

Comment: The `RenderImage` you pointed to takes in an `ILUT` but you pass in a `0`. How does your example compile? Also the method returns an `Image`, so the `new Bitmap` thing seems to be redundant.

Comment: 0 is the frame of the image, I only have 1 frame. I can also put () and will work. If I don't put New Image, the images are corrupted for some reason.

Comment: Dicom images are used in radiology and require special hardware to be displayed.  I'll guess you didn't spend tens of thousands of dollars on your machine.  So this is normal.

Comment: So, is there a way to reduce the size in memory of the Bitmaps?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is an answer from before the question was updated. I'm leaving it here because I think it adds value. If the community thinks otherwise I will delete it.

---

The [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat.aspx) that takes in a [PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) argument.

When loading/saving the image, use the `PixelFormat.Format16bpp**` value that matches your input format. For quick reference, here are the relevant formats:

`Format16bppArgb155`: The color information specifies 32,768 shades of color, of which 5 bits are red, 5 bits are green, 5 bits are blue, and 1 bit is alpha.

`Format16bppGrayScale`: The color information specifies 65536 shades of gray.

`Format16bppRgb555`: 5 bits each are used for the red, green, and blue components. The remaining bit is not used.

`Format16bppRgb565`: 5 bits are used for the red component, 6 bits are used for the green component, and 5 bits are used for the blue component.

Comment: well, it won't let me do that. See, I'm using Fo-Dicom which includes a method to create an Image object like this:
´MyImage = new Bitmap(img.RenderImage(0));´
I just don't see the option to add the pixelformat because I'm creating the Bitmap out of an Image object

Comment: @Matimont then please clarify your question with any custom libraries and methods you may be using. The telepathic reception is just a bit off today. :)

Comment: +1. @Matimont - it actually may be better to accept this answer and ask separate question where you clearly specify dependencies, show your code and clarify "store just the image with the original size" requirement (because the most obvious approach to satisfy the requirement is keep image in original stream/byte array)